# Simple Question - Trouble with Eigenvectors - Wolfram Alpha Didn't Help

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to teach myself singular value decomposition, and part of that is finding eigenvalues and Eeigenvectors.

I have a matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
So 
$$t(A)A =\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

So my Eigenvalues are
$$
\lambda_1 = 3,\qquad \lambda_2 = 2
$$

So now I need my eigenvectors.

To calculate the first one, I substitute $\lambda_1$ in
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda-2 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda-3
\end{bmatrix}$$
that becomes
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 3-2 & 0\\ 0 & 3-3\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
So when I solve for the eigenvector by multiplying this by $[x_1; x_2]$ and setting it to $0$ I get
\begin{cases}
x_1 = 0 \\
x_2 = 0
\end{cases}
But I cannot have a $[0 ; 0]$ eigenvector if I understand correctly, so I must be doing something wrong?

The result is supposed to be an eigenvector $[0 ; 1]$ but I fail to see how.

Answer (score 2):

When you multiply $\pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr} \pmatrix{x_1 \cr x_2\cr}$  you should get $\pmatrix{x_1 \cr 0\cr}$.  So $x_1 = 0$, but there is no restriction on $x_2$.  Thus $\pmatrix{0\cr x_2\cr}$ is an eigenvector, for any $x_2 \ne 0$.